# Transforming a 3D plane onto a 2D coordinate system

Tags: algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic, geometry, transformation

Say I have a set of points from a sensor which are all within a margin of error on a 2D plane somewhere in the 3D space. How would I go on about transforming the coordinates of the points onto a 2d coordinate system, so that for example the convex hulls of the points or the distances between the points don't change?

Comment: Is the plane known ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust not directly, but it could be approximated by finding the centroid of the points and using two other points in the cloud I think

Comment: You think correctly see [How to create 2d plot of arbitrary, coplanar 3d curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559920/2521214)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the equation of the plane (otherwise you can fit it by least-square or other), construct a new coordinate frame as follows:

- get the normal vector,
- form the cross product with an arbitrary vector having a different direction;
- form the cross product of the normal and the second vector,
- normalize all three and name the new axis z, x, y.

This creates an orthonormal basis to which you will transform the points. This corresponds to a rigid transform, that preserves all distances. You can drop the z to get the orthogonal projections of the points to the plane.