# Map triangle and line from 3d to 2d

Tags: 3d, geometry, mapping, 2d, line

I have a triangle in 3d and a line, they are lie in one plane. How can I map 5 points from 3d to 2d?

I can convert triangle to 2d, but can't do the same with line.

```
Vector2[] ConvertTo2d(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c)
{
    var aN = new Vector2(0, 0);
    var bN = new Vector2(0, 0);
    bN.x = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(b.x - a.x, 2f) + Mathf.Pow(b.y - a.y, 2f) + Mathf.Pow(b.z - a.z, 2f));
    var cN = new Vector2(0, 0);
    cN.x = ((b.x - a.x) * (c.x - a.x) + 
            (b.y - a.y) * (c.y - a.y) + 
            (b.z - a.z) * (c.z - a.z)) / bN.x;
    cN.y = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(c.x - a.x, 2f) + Mathf.Pow(c.y - a.y, 2f) + Mathf.Pow(c.z - a.z, 2f) - Mathf.Pow(cN.x, 2f));

    return new[] {aN, bN, cN};
}
```

Comment: What requirements do you have for the mapping? I'm guessing, it should be isometric. Anything else? There are still three degrees of freedom (rotation and translation in the 2D plane)

Comment: I need map it in that way, that one of 3 coordinates of every point was equal to each other. For example Z coordinate. In that way I can use X and Y coordinates to get 2d points

Comment: see the duplicate [How to create 2d plot of arbitrary, coplanar 3d curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559920/2521214) use the equations with origin ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted it to a code and it works!

```
var points = new Vector3[]
{
    triangleA,
    triangleB,
    triangleC,
    lineStart,
    lineEnd
};

var pointsIn2D = To2D(points);
```

```
Vector2[] To2D(Vector3[] points)
{
    var A = points[0];
    var B = points[1];
    var C = points[2];

    var U = B - A;
    var V = C - A;
    U /= U.magnitude;
    V /= U.magnitude;

    var W = Vector3.Cross(U, V);
    U = Vector3.Cross(V, W);

    Vector2[] pNew = new Vector2[points.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        var P = points[i];
        var xNew = Vector3.Dot(U, P);
        var yNew = Vector3.Dot(V, P);
        pNew[i] = new Vector2(xNew, yNew);
    }
    return pNew;
}
```